# Only Load 500 of the 2000 results in the JSON file with and Additional Load More Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I use this code to dynamically build a table from JSON data.

However, 2000 rows is too much for some devices and basically crashes the page. To solve this, I hid all but the top 500 results with CSS, with the intention of adding a `load all` button.

However, this doesn't work when you click on a colum header to sort the table. It still sorts the 2000 resutls, not the 500 which creates issues.

Is there a way of only calling in the first 500 results from the JSON file, in order of rank, and then using a "load all" function to load the remaining data on "button click", so that there is no unnecessary data to be sorted when not required?

I tried jQuery `.slice`, but that is basically just the same as doing the CSS `display:none` I'm already using, so doesn't work. I think `.hide`/`.show` does the same.

For example, is there a function that can grab the JSON, sort it, then disregard everything that isn't in the top 500, along with a function that can then load all data when a load all button is clicked?

[Live Site](https://lbrynomics.com/)

```js
    // Table builder

    $.getJSON('https://lbrynomics.com/data/top_2000.json', function(data) {
      var humanTimeSub = `${data.human_time_utc}`
      $(".human-time-sub").html(humanTimeSub)

      var sub_data = '';
      $.each(data.ranks, function(i, rank) {

        // Rank

        sub_data += '<tr class="ln-row" data-top500="' + data.top_500[i] + '" data-rank="' + data.ranks[i] + '" data-new="' + data.new_type[i] + '" lbrychannels="' + data.vanity_names[i].toLowerCase() + '"><td class="rank">' +
          rank + '</td>';

        // URL Bulider

        sub_data += '<td class="channel"><a href="https://odysee.com/@' +
          data.vanity_names[i] +
          ':' +
          data.claim_ids[i] +
          '" nsfw="' +
          data.is_nsfw[i] +
          '" grey="' +
          data.grey[i] +
          '" class="lbry-url" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" lbrychannel="' + data.vanity_names[i].toLowerCase() + '" title="LBRY Channel: ' + data.titles[i] + '">' +
          '<span class="at-sign">@</span>' + data.vanity_names[i] + '</a><span class="tag-1" ' + 'tag1="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-2" ' + 'tag2="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-3" ' + 'tag3="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-4" ' + 'tag4="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-5" ' + 'tag5="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-6" ' + 'tag6="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-7" ' + 'tag7="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span><span class="tag-8" ' + 'tag8="' + data.vanity_names[i] + '"></span></td>';

        // LBCs
 
        sub_data += '<td class="lbcs"><a href="https://currencio.co/lbc/usd/' +
        
          Math.ceil(data.lbc[i]) +
          '/#' + data.vanity_names[i] +
          '" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Convert ' + Math.ceil(data.lbc[i]).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' LBC to USD">' + 
          Math.ceil(data.lbc[i]) + 
          '</a></td>';
          
        // Followers

        sub_data += '<td class="subs">' +
          data.subscribers[i] + '</td>';

        // Views

        sub_data += '<td class="views" data-color="' +
          data.views[i] + '"><p>' +
          data.views[i] + '</p></td>';

        // reposts

        sub_data += '<td class="reposts" data-color="' +
          data.times_reposted[i] +
          '"><p>' +
          data.times_reposted[i] + '</p></td>';

        // Likes

        sub_data += '<td class="olikes"><p>' + data.likes[i] + '</p></td>';

        // Dislikes

        sub_data += '<td class="odislikes"><p>' + data.dislikes[i] + '</p></td>';
          
        // Folower Change

        sub_data += '<td class="follower-change change-color" data-new="' +
          data.new_type[i] +
          '"data-color="' +
          data.change[i] +
          '"><p>' +
          data.change[i] +
          '</p></td>';          

        // Views Change

        sub_data += '<td class="views-change change-color" data-color="' +
          data.views_change[i] +
          '"><p>' +
          data.views_change[i] + '</p></td>';

        //Reposts Change

        sub_data += '<td class="reposts-change change-color" data-color="' +
          data.times_reposted_change[i] +
          '"><p>' +
          data.times_reposted_change[i] + '</p></td>';

        // Rank Change

        sub_data += '<td class="rank-change change-color" data-color="' +
          data.rank_change[i] +
          '"><p>' +
          data.rank_change[i] + '</p></td></tr>';
      });
      $('#sub-stats').append(sub_data);

    });
     // Sort table
    
    const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
    const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => (v1 === null) - (v2 === null) || (isFinite(v1) && isFinite(v2) ?
    v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2))) (getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

    document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))

    .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
    .forEach((tr,i) => {tr.querySelector('.rank').innerText=i+1+'';table.appendChild(tr)});
})));
```

```css
/* TABLE */
#sub-stats {
    border: none;
    /*border-collapse: inherit;*/
    /*margin-right:15px;*/
}
tr:nth-child(-n+11) {
    background: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.3)!important;
}
tr:nth-child(n+102) {
    background: rgba(132, 132, 132, 0.09)!important;
}
#sub-stats td,
#sub-stats th {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #bbb;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
#sub-stats tr {
  background: rgba(93, 94, 97, 0.29);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  color: #bbb;
}
#sub-stats th {
  background: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sub-stats th:hover {
  background: #2d2d2d;
}
#sub-stats tr:hover {
  background: rgba(155, 169, 177, 0.22)!important;
  transition: 0s ease;
}
#sub-stats tr:hover td {
  color: #eee;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
#sub-stats .table-header tr:hover {
    background:none!important;
}
#sub-stats a {
  color: #ef436b;
}
#sub-stats a:visited {
  color: #ab4e70;
}
.lbcs a {
    color: #c3b8a3!important;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.lbcs a:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #5d574e;
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
td.lbcs {
    position:relative;
    padding: 0!important;
}
td.lbcs:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #5d574e;
}
.subs,
.follower-change,
.change, /*delete soon*/    
.rank-change,
.views,
.views-change,
.reposts,
.reposts-change,
.lncol3,
.lncol4,
.lncol5
{
  width: 5%;
}
.rank, .lncol1 {
  width: 2%;
}
.channel, .lncol2 {
  width: 63%;
}
.change-info {
    width: 20%;
    background:#286dc1;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding-top: 8px!important;
    padding-bottom: 6px!important;
    text-align:center;
}
.lncol1, .lncol2, .lncol3, .lncol4, .lncol5, .change-info {
    display:inline-block;

}
/*Date*/

.data-time {
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px 10px 3px 10px;
    background: #444444;
    font-size: 80%;
    display: inline-block;

}
.human-time-sub {
    color:#777;
}
.data-time-offline {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /*color: #FFC107;*/
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-size: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px!important;
}

.live {
  font-size: 90%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffa500;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  background: #1d1d1d;
}

/*Table Data CSS*/


.over-7-empty {
  border:none!important;
  background:none!important;
}
.over-7-fill {
    text-align:center;
    background:#286dc1!important;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0!important;
    border:none;
}
.over-7-empty, .over-7-fill {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.table-header th {
  color:#fff!important;
  border:none!important;
  padding: 5px!important;
}
.table-header tr {
    background: none!important;
}
p.table-headers {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.rank-header/*, .channel-header*/ {
  pointer-events:none!important;
}
td.olikes {
    color: #c5a855!important;
}
td.odislikes {
    color: #c36367!important;
}
.change-color {
  color: #00ff8f!important;
}
.ln-table-header th, .ln-sticky {
  position: sticky!important;
  height: 80px; 
  z-index:999999!important;
  top: -2px;
}
.ln-table-header th {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #444;
  background: #333333!important;
  border: none!important;
  padding: 10px 4px 10px 15px!important;
}

.ln-table-header th.stats-change {
    background: #393c42!important;
}
  td[data-color*="-"] {
  color: red!important;
}

td[data-color="0"] {
  color: #bbb!important;
}


/* NEW */



td[data-new^="n"] p {
  visibility: hidden;
}
tr[data-new^="n"] td:nth-child(n+10) p {
    display: none!important;
}

td:nth-child(9)[data-new="n1"] p:before {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "NEW"!important;
    color: #49b9ff;
    font-size: 70%;
    background: #262626;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    display: inline;
}
td:nth-child(9)[data-new="n2"] p:before {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "NEW"!important;
    color: #ff0052;
    font-size: 70%;
    background: #262626;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    display: inline;
} 


tr[data-new^="n"] {
    filter: brightness(1.15)!important;
}


td[data-new^="n"] {
  padding-left: 2px!important;
}
tr[data-new^="n"] td:nth-child(n+9), tr[data-color="null"] td:nth-child(n+9) {
    border: none!important;
}
tr[data-new^="n"] a {
    filter: grayscale(5%) hue-rotate(2deg) brightness(0.95)!important;
}
td:nth-child(9), td:nth-child(10), td:nth-child(11), td:nth-child(12) {
  background:rgba(143, 183, 255, 0.07);
}

/* END NEW */



td a[nsfw="true"],
td a[grey="true"],
a[nsfw="true"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
td a[nsfw="true"] {
    color:#666!important;
}
td a[nsfw="true"]:after,
.nsfw {
  font-size: 70%;
  content: "NSFW";
  color: #666;
  background: #262626;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.new {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #49b9ff;
  background: #262626;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.new5 {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #ff0052;
  background: #262626;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

#sub-stats tbody {
 box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

table.ln-tables {
    border:none!important;
}
.ln-tables  {
    display: table-cell;
    background:#333!important;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.ln-tables  .ln-table-header {
    font-size: 1em;
    background:#292929!important;
}
.entry-content tr td, body.et-pb-preview #main-content .container tr td {
    padding: 0;
}
.ln-tables tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.05) !important;
    background:#333!important;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#sub-stats td {
    padding:5px 20px;
}
.ln-tables  .views, #view-stats .rank {
    color:888!important;
}
.ln-tables  th {
    background: #3e3b3b !important;
    color:#777!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
.at-sign {
    color: #616161;
}
.ln-tables  a {
    color:#807979;
}
/*WIDGETS*/

.yts-status::first-letter {
  text-transform:capitalize!important;
}
/* Deprecated */
/*
.big-tips-1h a {color: #ffd000;}
.big-tips-24h a {color: #ff0051;}
.big-tips-7d a {color: #4396ef;}
.big-tips-30d a {color: #99ff00;}
*/
.big-supports-1h a {color: #ffd000;}
.big-supports-24h a {color: #ff0051;}
.big-supports-7d a {color: #4396ef;}
.big-supports-30d a {color: #99ff00;}
.big-boosts-total a {color: #ff00ff;}

.ccws2 {
  padding-top: 53px!important;
  margin: 50px 0!important;
  font-size: 20px!important;
  transform:scale(1) rotate(0)!important;
  transition: 0.7s ease!important;
  background: #262626!important;
  cursor: grab;
}
.ccws2:hover {
  padding-top: 58px !important;
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg) !important;
  transition: 0.7s ease!important;
}
.ccws2 a {
    text-shadow: 0 0 11px;
    transition: 0.7s ease!important;
}
.ccws2:hover a {
    color:#ff0051!important;
    transition: 0.7s ease!important;    
}
 .ccws2:hover a[nsfw="true"] {
    color: #444!important;
    cursor: not-allowed!important;
}

.ccwht {
    height: 7vh!important;
    padding: 10px 10px!important;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle!important;
    width: 100vw!important;
}
.ccwht h3 {
    font-size: 0.95rem!important;
    transition: .7s ease!important;
    vertical-align:middle!important;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0!important;
}
.help:hover p {
    text-transform: unset!important;
    color:#666!important;
    font-weight:400!important;
}
/* Mobile Styles*/
/* Footer Bio */

.bio-img {
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:0;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:6px;
  box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.bio-img:hover {
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* Accessability Button */
.control-box {
  z-index:99999;
}
.read {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
}
.read-button {
    vertical-align: middle!important;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    border: none;
    color: #999;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*cursor: pointer!important;*/
    cursor: not-allowed!important;  
}
.read-button:hover {
  background: #3f3f3f;

}
.control-panel .read-button:hover {
  transform:scale(1)!important;
  cursor: initial;

}
.readability {
  filter: brightness(1.2) contrast(1.2) saturate(1.1)!important;
}
.ln-buttons {
    position: fixed!important;
    top: 50%!important;
    bottom: auto;
}
.button-text {
  position:absolute; top:3px;
  left:-20px;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 0.96em;
}

/* LBRYnomics Stats */

input#lbry_channel_search {
    background: #3d3d3d;
    border: 1px solid #292929;
    color: #ef436b;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0 rgb(23 23 23 / 23%);
}
.ln-info-menu-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999999999;
    left: 64px!important;
    top: 80px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-size: 120%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ln-info {
  position:absolute;
  width:350px;
  height:420px;
  background:#333;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:-232px;
  margin-top:-184px;
  padding:30px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.lnm-note {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4em!important;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.ln-info:hover {
    background:#333!important;
}
.ln-info p {
    padding-bottom: 2px!important;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
.ln-info h4 {
  padding-bottom: 15px!important;
}
hr.ln-info-hr {
    border: 1px solid #3e3e3e!important;
    margin:9px 0!important;
}
.iCharts {
}
.iCharts h2 {
  color:#444;
  margin:0;
  line-height:1.25em;
  padding:20px 4px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-size:1.6vmax;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  width:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #282828 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);
} 
.iCharts div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;
}
.iCharts h2::before, .flash-icon::before {
    content: "";
    background: #444;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:0.5px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
} 
.iCharts div:hover h2::before, .flash-icon::before {
  background:#b32544!important;
  animation: Pulsate 1s ease infinite;
}

@media (min-width:1600px) {
 .iCharts h2 {
  font-size:1.8em;
} 
 
}
@media (max-width:980px) {
 .iCharts h2 {
  font-size:3vmax;
} 
}
@media (min-width:981px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .ccws2 {
    font-size: 22px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    background-color: #222!important;
    border-radius: 180px 180px 180px 180px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    border-width: 10px!important;
    margin: 20px 0 40px!important;
    padding-top: 55px!important;
    transform:scale(0.75) rotate(0) !important;     
  }
  .ccws2:hover {
    padding-top: 55px!important;
    transform:scale(0.85) rotate(359.99deg) !important;   
    }
}
    
@media (min-width:981px) {
.lbry-widgets .lwc1, .lbry-widgets .lwc2, .lbry-widgets .lwc3, .lbry-widgets .lwc4, .lbry-widgets .lwc5 {
    width:100%!important;
    margin-right: 1.7%!important;
}
.lbry-widgets .lwc6 {
    width:100%!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
}/*
.ccwht h3 {
    font-size: 0.8rem!important;
    transition: .7s ease!important;
}*/
}
@media (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 980px)  {
.lbry-widgets .lwc1, .lbry-widgets .lwc2, .lbry-widgets .lwc4, .lbry-widgets .lwc5 {
    width:30%!important;
    margin-right: 3.333%!important;
}
.lbry-widgets .lwc3, .lbry-widgets .lwc3 {
    width:33.333%!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
}/*
.ccwht h3 {
    font-size: 0.7rem!important;
    transition: .7s ease!important;
}*/
  @media (max-width:980px) {
    .logo-box {
    transform: scale(none) translate(2.6px, 20px);
    }
    .logo-box:hover {
    transform: scale(none) translate(2.6px, 20px);
    }
    .lbryn-logo {
    margin-right: -6px;
    }
    .vertical-info-text {
    position: relative!important;
    display:inline-block!important;
    }
    .vertical-info-text-hide {
    display: none!important;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {  
    .lbryn-logo {
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
      }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .subs,
    .follower-change,
    .change, /*delete soon*/    
    .rank-change,
    .views,
    .views-change,
    .reposts,
    .reposts-change
    {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .rank {
    width: 1%;
  }
  .channel {
    width: 78%;
  }
  .entry-content tr th {
    padding: 8px 4px!important;
    font-size: 70%;
    line-height: 1.4em;
  }
  .entry-content tr td {
    /*padding: 4px 6px!important;*/
    font-size: 70%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .entry-content tr th {
    padding: 8px 4px!important;
    font-size: 50%;
    line-height: 1.4em;
  }
  .entry-content tr td {
    /*padding: 4px 6px!important;*/
    font-size: 50%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
  }
.lbry-widgets .lwc1, .lbry-widgets .lwc3, .lbry-widgets .lwc5 {
    width:100%!important;
    /*margin-right: 1%!important;*/
  }
.lbry-widgets .lwc2, .lbry-widgets .lwc4, .lbry-widgets .lwc6 {
    width:100%!important;
    /*margin-right: 0!important;*/
  } 
}   
@media (max-width:1340px) { 
    #top-table-box, .lbry-widgets {
    zoom: 0.9;  
    }
    .lbry-widgets h3 {
    font-size: 0.8em!important;
    line-height: 1.4em!important;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1200px) { 
    #top-table-box {
    zoom: 0.8;  
    }
    th, td, tr, tbody {
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 12px!important;
    }
    .change-panel {
    width:300px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:900px) {  
    #top-table-box {
    zoom: 0.7;  
    }
    .change-panel {
    width:300px;
    }
    .change-text {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {  
    .change-text {
    top: 6px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .control-box {
    top: 75%!important;
}
}

@media (max-width:700px) {  
    .change-panel {
    width: 208px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {  
    #top-table-box {
    zoom: 0.6;  
    }
    .change-panel {
    width: 215px;
    }
    .control-box {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:414px) {  
    #top-table-box {
    zoom: 0.5;  
    }
}
/* Interactive Charts*/
@media (min-width:1580px) { 
    .chart-buttons {
        display:none!important;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1579px) { 
    .chart-warning {
    }
    .chart-iframe, .chart-title, .chart-titles  {
        display:none;
    }
    .chart-buttons {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1580px) { 
    .chart-warning {
        display:none!important;
    }
}

col.all-columns.lnt-column-4 {
    border: 1px solid #999!important; 
    background: #4e4e4e!important;
    color:red!important;
}

tr[data-top500="false"] {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sticky-header" id="sub-stats">
<colgroup>
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-1">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-2">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-3">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-4">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-5">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-6">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-7">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-8">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-9">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-10">
    <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-11">
</colgroup>
<thead class="table-header">
<tr>
<th colspan="8" class="over-7-empty"></th>
  <th colspan="4" class="over-7-fill">Change Over 7 Days</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr class="ln-table-header ln-sticky">
<th title="Rank For The Current Sorted Column" class="rank-header"><p class="table-headers">Rank</p></th>
<th title="LBRY Channel Name"><p class="table-headers">Channel</p></th>
<th title="Tips + Supports Currently Staked"><p class="table-headers">Value</p></th>
<th title="Total LBRY Channel Followers"><p class="table-headers">Follows</p></th>  
<th title="Total LBRY Channel Content Views"><p class="table-headers">Views</p></th>
<th title="Total Amount of Content Reposts"><p class="table-headers">Reposts</p></th>   
<th title="Total Odysee likes"><p class="table-headers">Likes</p></th>
<th title="Total Odysee dislikes"><p class="table-headers">Dislikes</p></th>     
<th class="stats-change" title="Channel Follower Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Follows</p></th>
<th class="stats-change" title="Channel Content Views Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Views</p></th>
<th class="stats-change" title="Repost Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Reposts</p></th>   
<th class="stats-change" title="Rank Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Rank</p></th>
</tr>
<tbody>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think you'll solve the problem you have with just CSS. You'll need to work on the way you return this result to break it into chunks (ie: pagination).

Comment: That's the point. I'm looking for a way to load only the JSON required with JS. I'll update the question to make it more obvious.

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "top" in "top 500". Typically, "top 500" depends on sort order; "top 500 by rank" or "top 500 by name". So, if you only sort the *first* 500 records, users could get the wrong idea about what data are present in the remaining 1500 records. Getting only some records from the server depends on the server returning the records.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to perform paging on the server side but if that's not possible at the moment then you can try using the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) library for this and run the below statement:

`const result = _.take(_.drop(yourJSONData, skipCount), takeCount);`

The `_.drop` method will basically skip `skipCount` number of records and `._take` method will then take `takeCount` no. of records after that.

So let's say you set the `skipCount = 2`, `takeCount = 10` and `yourJSONDATA.length` is 20 the `result` would basically contain 3rd-13th rows in it.

You can also sort your data by  using `_.sortBy` method.

If needed, you can experiment with different lodash methods from [here](https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/).

Answer (score 1):

With LokiJS database, load JSON in database, sort, get first results.  
https://techfort.github.io/LokiJS/

How to load a JSON file into db 
https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/issues/658

```
var data = loadPeople();
var db = new loki('test.db');
var people = db.addCollection('people');
people.insert(data);
```

https://techfort.github.io/LokiJS/tutorial-Query%20Examples.html 
simplesort - just pass a property name and your resulset will be sorted by this. 
sort - allows you to provide your own comparison function to sort the resultset with.